# yii gii 403 forbidden 2.0 basic template

Tags: php, yii

[image: here a picture]

my yii configuration file
project/basic/config/web.php

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
  //  $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';

    //Gourav Kamboj para dar acceso a conectarse gii
    //Cambiar la IP
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class'=> 'yii\gii\Module',
        'allowedIPs'=> ['127.0.0.1','::1','192.168.179.28'],
    ];


}
```

I have searched on internet a lot but nobody say about this. There are some solution for  the version 1.0.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was that i am using the virtual machine as a server ubuntu and the windows 8 as a client. So, the server IP was not in same network. Simply I have changed the IP of both machine to be in the same network. it works. viola !!!

Comment: Do you adjust your IP address in  'allowedIPs'=> ['127.0.0.1','::1','192.168.179.28'] section ?

Comment: yes, I changed my host IP address at the same network. The IP of host is 192.168.179.35. So now the I can ping each other.